# Collision Detection of 3D Cuboids

Tags: geometry

So, in my simulation I have two 3D axis-aligned cuboids, and both have moved in a straight line since last frame. They are now colliding with each other (they weren't before).

How do I determine which sides of the cuboids collided? (e.g. top-and bottom, left and right, or front and back) It seems like a trivial problem, but there is too much in motion here for me to figure it out.

So far, I have already tried comparing the distance moved, but the corners of the objects will "catch" the other object on a different side from what the distance components indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you know that the cuboids have collided, you should be able to tell from their relative velocity which sides must have collided with each other.

If the relative velocity of $B$ with respect to $A$ is, say, $-\hat{z}$, then the bottom face of $B$ collided with the top face of $A$.

If the relative velocity is diagonal, then the dimensions of the cuboids comes into play, since a fatter side would hit before a slimmer one.

The most general way will be to solve for the times of intersection in each axis. For instance: for the right side of $A$ colliding with the left side of $B$:

$x_{A}(t) - x_{A}(0) = v_{A,x} t + \frac{\text{width}_A}{2} $

$x_{B}(t) - x_{B}(0)= v_{B,x}t - \frac{\text{width}_B}{2}$

$x_B(t) = x_A(t)$

$t = \frac{\text{width}_A + \text{width}_B + x_{A}(0) - x_{B}(0) }{2(v_B - v_A)}$

and likewise for left-right, top-bottom, bottom-top, front-back, back-front.

And solve for the intersection time by setting these equal, in each of the dimensions. The smallest time will tell you which dimension intersected first. If two are the same, they collided on the shared corner.

This is optimizeable in many ways. For instance: use only relative velocities and displacements; set $t$ to the time of the previous frame. (You can also use it to test collisions: if $t$ is a time between the previous frame and the current one, the figures have overlapped in that time.)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's the highest time, and you have to ignore axes on which the cuboids are already intersecting. Aside from that, good answer. This set me on the right track.